# several conditions in the same sql query (having and min)

Tags: sql, having

I have a table with these variables and I want to select the row where sum of the VALUE is greater than 1000 and at the same time the MONTH is the minimum

```
|CLIENT     |MONTH         |VALUE
|1          |1             |500            
|1          |2             |1050
|1          |3             |1100
```

the result should be this:

```
|CLIENT|MONTH|VALUE
|1     |2    |1050
```

Is it possible to do it in only one query?

My attempt:

```
       SELECT 
       client,            
       SUM(value) AS SUM_of_value, 
       MIN(month) AS MIN_of_month, 

      FROM mytable 
      GROUP BY 1
      having SUM_of_value>1000;
```

Comment: Why do you aggregate if you want a single row from the table?

Comment: because I want to select the smaller month (min of month) in which the SUM function of "value" is greater than 1000, so it's not a WHERE condintion

Comment: If there are more than 1 row per month then the sum of the rows could be > 1000 but each row  could be < 1000. What is your expect result in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row, then you can use `order by`:

```
select t.*
from mytable
where value > 1000
order by month
fetch first 1 row only;
```

I'm not sure why your query refers to "sum of value", because there is only one value per month for the data in the question.

EDIT:

Based on the comment, you do seem to want an aggregation query:

```
select client, month, sum(value)
from 
group by client, month
having sum(value) > 1000
order by month
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: because I want to select the smaller month (min of month) in which the SUM function of "value" is greater than 1000, so it's not a WHERE condition on the column value. Also because in my real table there could be more than one value per month. thanks

Comment: @progster . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  You should include appropriate sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You coud try using a join between  your query and the query group by client and month

```
select  t.client,  t2.SUM_of_value, t2.MIN_of_month
from  (
       SELECT 
       client,            
       SUM(value) AS SUM_of_value, 
       MIN(month) AS MIN_of_month, 
       FROM mytable 
       GROUP BY 1
       having SUM_of_value>1000;
) t1 
inner join (
       SELECT 
       client,            
       month , 
       SUM(value) AS SUM_of_value
       FROM mytable 
       GROUP BY 1,2
       having SUM_of_value>1000;
) t2 ON t2.client = t1.client 
    AND t2.month  = t1.MIN_of_month
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 1 `VALUE` per each `MONTH` then use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.CLIENT, t.MONTH, t.VALUE
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by client order by month) rn
  from mytable
  where value > 1000
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rEMiynActDxn2wTRnV7fZc/2).
Results:

```
| CLIENT | MONTH | VALUE |
| ------ | ----- | ----- |
| 1      | 2     | 1050  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Gordon and Forpas. Your sample data and output seems too simplistic. I think you would want one row per client.

```
select t.client, t.month, t.value
from (
select client, month, sum(value) as value, row_number() over (partition by client order by month) rn
from my_table
group by client, month
having sum(value) > 1000
) t
where t.rn = 1
```